# Sort nested divs inside unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have the following html ul:

```
<ul id="actionList">
  <li>
  <span>
    <h4>xyz</h4>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test2</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test3</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test1</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <h4>abc</h4>
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test5</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test4</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test6</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to sort the `.item` divs alphabetically based on the `.title` div.

**What I tried:**

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.item').sort(function(a, b) {
    var $aTitle = $(a).find('.title'), $bTitle = $(b).find('.title');
  return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($aTitle.text().toLowerCase(), $bTitle.text().toLowerCase());
});

var container = $(".list");
container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
container.parent().append(container);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to come out with any output.

I'm thinking this has to do with the fact that the `.list` is a class instead of id and therefore there are multiple.

I tried replacing `container.parent()` with `$('body')` just to see if it is even outputting anything, and I found that it was sorting the `.item` divs... just gathering them all and sorting them. This was causing it to have two sets of all test{1-6}.

Is this even possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function uses bad IDs / classes ?

You can use this :

```
// loop through all .list
$('.list').each(function() {
  // loop through all .item inside .list
  $(this).find('.item').sort(function(a, b) {
    // test .title text
    if ($(a).find('.title').text() < $(b).find('.title').text()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  // append sort to .list
  }).appendTo($(this));
});
```

```js
$('.list').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.item').sort(function(a, b) {
    if ($(a).find('.title').text() < $(b).find('.title').text()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }).appendTo($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="actionList">
  <li>
    <span>
    <h4>xyz</h4>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test2</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test3</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test1</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <h4>abc</h4>
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test5</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test4</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test6</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm normally a back-end developer so forgive me if my html is a mess, but could you elaborate on "Your function uses bad IDs / classes ?"
I'm still learning, so knowing what I did wrong would really help. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkC I suppose he means that the classes `.action` or `.topic` are nowhere to be seen

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to order `each` `.list` separately:

```js
$('.list').each(function() {
  // find .item's inside 'this' div
  divs = $('.item', this).sort(function(a, b) {
    // get immediate .title children
    return $(a).children('.title').text() > $(b).children('.title').text()
  })
  // replace contents of this .list with ordered divs
  $(this).html(divs)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="actionList">
  <li>
    <span>
    <h4>xyz</h4>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test2</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test3</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="title">test1</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <h4>abc</h4>
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test5</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test4</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p class="title">test6</p>
          <button class="deleteButton" tabindex="-1">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```